# Script Component failed the post-execute phase and returned error code 0x80004002

Tags: c#, ssis

SSIS pakage throw an errror "**[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Script Component failed the post-execute phase and returned error code 0x80004002.

**"
In Script component its shows task run successfully but Control flow task shows Error.

[image: Control flow task]

[image: Data flow Task]

Here is my Script task Code:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    #region Getting Variable values 

    // Getting DBPackage variable value. 
    Object varDBPackage;
    IDTSVariables100 vars = null;
    VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::DBPackage");
    VariableDispenser.GetVariables(out vars);

    // Getting ReportPath variable value. 
    Object varReportPath;
    IDTSVariables100 ReportPath = null;
    VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::ReportPath");
    VariableDispenser.GetVariables(out ReportPath);

    // Getting GetAllProvidersOutput variable value. 
    Object varGetAllProvidersOutput;
    IDTSVariables100 GetAllProvidersOutput = null;
    VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::GetAllProvidersOutput");
    VariableDispenser.GetVariables(out GetAllProvidersOutput);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    try
    {
        // Assign values into variable
        varDBPackage = (Object)vars["User::DBPackage"].Value;
        varReportPath = ReportPath["User::ReportPath"].Value;
        varGetAllProvidersOutput = GetAllProvidersOutput["User::GetAllProvidersOutput"].Value;

        // Extract the data from the object variable into the table and fetching Description from XML.
        da.Fill(dt, varDBPackage);


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        varDBPackage = null;
        varReportPath = null;
        varGetAllProvidersOutput = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        vars.Unlock();
        ReportPath.Unlock();
        GetAllProvidersOutput.Unlock();
    }

    #endregion

    String GetAllProvidersOutputPath = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", varReportPath.ToString(), Convert.ToString(varGetAllProvidersOutput));
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(GetAllProvidersOutputPath);
    var prefix = xDoc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("d1p1");

    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        string code = item["CODPROVIDERCODE"].ToString().ToUpper();
        string submissionEndDate = item["MAXSUBMISSIONENDDATE"].ToString();
        var node = xDoc.Root.Element(prefix + "AARetrieve")
        .Elements(prefix + "Organization")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute(prefix + "Code").Value.ToUpper() == code);

        string description = string.Empty;
        if (node != null)
            description = node.Elements(prefix + "OrganizationData").FirstOrDefault().Elements().Select(x => x.Attribute("Description").Value).FirstOrDefault();

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.CODPROVIDERCODE = (item["CODPROVIDERCODE"].ToString());
        Output0Buffer.MAXSUBMISSIONENDDATE = Convert.ToDateTime(item["MAXSUBMISSIONENDDATE"]);
        Output0Buffer.PROVIDERDESCRIPTION = description;
    }
}
```

Error:

[Script Component [23]] Error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSVariables100'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{D1A469BC-F371-4D15-832F-BACB50C162E9}' failed due to the following error: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)).
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PostExecute()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPostExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)

I am quite new in SSIS so kindly guide me what causes the Issue.

Thanks

Comment: try to set breakpoints in your script component to see if there is any data coming through or it does as expected.

Comment: Check the Output pane for any additional error messages or warnings.

Comment: What is that line coming off of the Execute SQL task? (to the right). It looks like there is some logic going on there that may not be reflected in your data flow task. Just a guess at this point as I do not know the extent of all of the components.

Comment: @TabAlleman kindly look my Edit i have added Error which i get in Progress.